# Dual booting Ubuntu 21.10 and Fedora 35 with encryption for both?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

absolute linux noob here. I want to dual boot Ubuntu 21.10 and Fedora 35. There are already quite a few tutorials on doing exactly this but very few go into doing it while also encrypting both installations and the ones that do are a bit too complicated for me at the moment. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: We don't know what is easy for you...

Comment: @Community I'm looking to dual boot Ubuntu with Fedora but also encrypt both partitions. While installing only Ubuntu, I can choose to use LVM and encrypt the Ubuntu partition but when I choose "something else" in installation type, this option is no longer available.

Comment: @ChanganAuto admittedly, not much. But something that shows the steps and also goes into what it's doing would be much appreciated. Or if you can point me to another resource, that would be cool too.